# Android: Convert String back to ListArray

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

I am having trouble figuring out how to go from a string back into the list array.

I currently have a list array to go into a string like the following:

```
String joined = TextUtils.join(",", blacklistedpins):
```

I have that to send the string into a database. However now when I want to read that string from the database I need to take it and put it back into the list array. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is `blacklistedpins` array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` method as follows:

```
String tokens[] = joined.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 List<String> blacklistedpins = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...use split method to reverse the effect of string.

```
  List<String> blacklistedpins = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
```